# Get the Output from the MsTest.exe when running through the commandline

Tags: mstest

Need to get the **Pass or fail status from the particular test run when we run the test cases from the MsTest.exe** via command-line.

Comment: I think it's quite clear the OP wants to have mstest.exe standard out be displayed in the console when you run the test from the command line.  It's a very reasonable request.  Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the /detail and /usestderr command-line options to force test status to be returned to the command-line. For details, please read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=VS.100).aspx